# Automapper ProjectTo adds ToList into child properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, automapper

I use projection to map the Entity classes to DTOs using Entity Framework Core. However, projection adds ToList into child collection properties and this slows down the query a lot.

Company Entity:

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        Employees = new List<CompanyEmployee>();
    }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CompanyEmployee> Employees { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Company DTO:

```
public class CompanyDTO
{
    public CompanyDTO()
    {
        CompanyEmployees = new List<EmployeeDTO>();
    }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeDTO> CompanyEmployees { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Configuration:

```
CreateMap<Company, CompanyDTO>()
    .ForMember(c => c.CompanyEmployees, a => a.MapFrom(src => src.Employees));
CreateMap<CompanyEmployee, EmployeeDTO>();
```

Query:

```
UnitOfWork.Repository<Company>()
    .ProjectTo<CompanyDTO>(AutoMapper.Mapper.Configuration)
    .Take(10)
    .ToList();
```

Inspecting the generated query using the `Expression` property after `ProjectTo` yields the following:

```
Company.AsNoTracking()
    .Select(dtoCompany => new CompanyDTO() 
    {
        Address = dtoCompany.Address, 
        ...
        CompanyEmployees = dtoCompany.Employees.Select(dtoCompanyEmployee => new EmployeeDTO() 
                            {
                                CreatedDate = dtoCompanyEmployee.CreatedDate, 
                                ...
                            }).ToList() // WHY??????
    })
```

That `ToList` call causes to run select queries for each entity which is not what I want as you have guessed. I tested the query without that `ToList` (by manually copying the expression and running it) and everything works as expected. How can I prevent AutoMapper adding that call? I tried changing `List` type in DTO to `IEnumerable` but nothing changed..

Comment: When the DTO uses `ICollection<T>`, the result of `Select` is `IEnumerable<T>` and cannot be assigned directly (compile time error), so `ToList` is definitely needed. The problem is somewhere else in your code. `ProjectTo` creates LINQ to Entities query which normally executes server side (SQL), so there should not be separate queries for each entity. Are you sure your repository returns real EF queryable? Did you check the generated SQL?

Comment: Repository returns IQueryable and I couldn't inspect the query since EF Core 2 has no way (as I know of) to allow us inspect the query and since I use PostgreSQL, I need the log files which is not in my possession etc. etc. :) Removing that ToList call fixes everything though and I thought that there should be a way to prevent that?

Comment: Ah, EF **Core**. Actually `ToList` in EF Core 2.1 is solving the multiple subquery problem - see [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries). I'm using it a lot and it really works. Not sure why it has the opposite effect for you.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thanks for the link. What I don't get is that it should be a "optimization" as they call it because it prevents "N + 1" problem but the query works x100 faster (at least) when there is no ToList..

Comment: Most likely the problem lies with the PostgreSQL EF provider.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let ignore the EF Core affect of the `ToList` call and concentrate on AutoMapper `ProjectTo`.

The behavior is hardcoded in [`EnumerableExpressionBinder`](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/QueryableExtensions/Impl/EnumerableExpressionBinder.cs#L35) class:

```
expression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), propertyMap.DestinationPropertyType.IsArray ? "ToArray" : "ToList", new[] { destinationListType }, expression);
```

This class in part of the AutoMapper QueryableExtensions processing pipeline and is responsible for converting source enumerable to destination enumerable. And as we can see, it always emits either `ToArray` or `ToList`.

In fact when the destination member type is `ICollection<T>` or `IList<T>`, the `ToList` call is needed because otherwise the expression won't compile. But when the destination member type is `IEnumerable<T>`, this is arbitrary.

So if you want to get rid of that behavior in the aforementioned scenario, you can inject a custom `IExpressionBinder` *before* the `EnumerableExpressionBinder` (the binders are called in order until `IsMatch` returns `true`) like this (

```
namespace AutoMapper
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using AutoMapper.Configuration.Internal;
    using AutoMapper.Mappers.Internal;
    using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions;
    using AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Impl;

    public class GenericEnumerableExpressionBinder : IExpressionBinder
    {
        public bool IsMatch(PropertyMap propertyMap, TypeMap propertyTypeMap, ExpressionResolutionResult result) =>
            propertyMap.DestinationPropertyType.IsGenericType &&
            propertyMap.DestinationPropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>) &&
            PrimitiveHelper.IsEnumerableType(propertyMap.SourceType);

        public MemberAssignment Build(IConfigurationProvider configuration, PropertyMap propertyMap, TypeMap propertyTypeMap, ExpressionRequest request, ExpressionResolutionResult result, IDictionary<ExpressionRequest, int> typePairCount, LetPropertyMaps letPropertyMaps)
            => BindEnumerableExpression(configuration, propertyMap, request, result, typePairCount, letPropertyMaps);

        private static MemberAssignment BindEnumerableExpression(IConfigurationProvider configuration, PropertyMap propertyMap, ExpressionRequest request, ExpressionResolutionResult result, IDictionary<ExpressionRequest, int> typePairCount, LetPropertyMaps letPropertyMaps)
        {
            var expression = result.ResolutionExpression;

            if (propertyMap.DestinationPropertyType != expression.Type)
            {
                var destinationListType = ElementTypeHelper.GetElementType(propertyMap.DestinationPropertyType);
                var sourceListType = ElementTypeHelper.GetElementType(propertyMap.SourceType);
                var listTypePair = new ExpressionRequest(sourceListType, destinationListType, request.MembersToExpand, request);
                var transformedExpressions = configuration.ExpressionBuilder.CreateMapExpression(listTypePair, typePairCount, letPropertyMaps.New());
                if (transformedExpressions == null) return null;
                expression = transformedExpressions.Aggregate(expression, (source, lambda) => Select(source, lambda));
            }

            return Expression.Bind(propertyMap.DestinationProperty, expression);
        }

        private static Expression Select(Expression source, LambdaExpression lambda)
        {
            return Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "Select", new[] { lambda.Parameters[0].Type, lambda.ReturnType }, source, lambda);
        }

        public static void InsertTo(List<IExpressionBinder> binders) =>
            binders.Insert(binders.FindIndex(b => b is EnumerableExpressionBinder), new GenericEnumerableExpressionBinder());
    }
}
```

It's basically a modified copy of the `EnumerableExpressionBinder` with different `IsMatch` check and removed `ToList` call emit code.

Now if you inject it to your AutoMapper configuration:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    GenericEnumerableExpressionBinder.InsertTo(cfg.Advanced.QueryableBinders);
    // ...
});
```

and make your DTO collection type `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public IEnumerable<EmployeeDTO> CompanyEmployees { get; set; }
```

the `ProjectTo` will generate expression with `Select` but w/o `ToList`.

Comment: Thats great, thanks for the effort. I will integrate it in a few days when I'm available.

Comment: @sotn Why don't you just select this answer as accepted answer if it solved your problem or why don't you leave a comment if it did not solve?

Comment: @Mansur I forgot. Selected it as accepted answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe this (official) [AutoMapper.EF6](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.EF6/blob/master/src/AutoMapper.EF6/EntityFrameworkExtensions.cs) extension would help.
As you can see on the bottom, it implements `ProjectToQueryable` method:

```cs
public static IQueryable<TDestination> ProjectToQueryable<TDestination>(this IQueryable queryable, object parameters)
  {
    return queryable.ProjectTo<TDestination>(parameters).DecompileAsync();
  }
```