# Optimization of correlated subqueries with Automapper

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, automapper

**Update:**
Automapper applies this automatically in simple cases since it [already adds a `ToList()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218340/automapper-projectto-adds-tolist-into-child-properties). The issue I am seeing that led me to open this question turns out to be a more complicated issue (the [SoftwareIds member](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/3f1d0a9a06d19a56161c4479ca6c13ae69e07247/src/FilterLists.Services/FilterList/MappingProfiles/ListSummaryDtoMappingProfile.cs#L14) is the culprit of `N+1`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52368567/optimization-of-correlated-subqueries-with-automapper#comment91755577_52368567).).

---

In EF Core 2.1, we gained support for adding `ToList()` on a LINQ subquery to buffer results and avoid N+1 database queries. ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries)) This works great on plain LINQ queries against a DbContext.

However, if I have an Automapper profile that results in N+1 queries:

```
    public MyMappingProfile() =>
        CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDto>().ForMember(e => e.MyCollectionProp, o => o.MapFrom(l => l.MyCollectionPropMany.Select(la => la.MyCollectionEntity)))
```

Adding `ToList()` throws an exception:

```
    public MyMappingProfile() =>
        CreateMap<MyEntity, MyDto>().ForMember(e => e.MyCollectionProp, o => o.MapFrom(l => l.MyCollectionPropMany.Select(la => la.MyCollectionEntity).ToList()))
```

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Could not parse expression
>   'MyDto.MyCollectionPropMany.Select(la =>
>   la.MyCollectionEntity).ToList()': This overload of the method
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList' is currently not supported.'

Is there a way to enable subquery buffering in an Automapper profile?

Models:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MyCollectionPropMany> MyCollectionPropManys { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyCollectionPropMany
{
    public int MyEntityId { get; set; }
    public MyEntity MyEntity { get; set; }
    public int MyCollectionPropId { get; set; }
    public MyCollectionProp MyCollectionProp { get; set; }
}

public class MyCollectionProp
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<MyCollectionPropMany> MyCollectionPropManys { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MyCollectionPropDto> MyCollectionPropDtos { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class MyCollectionPropDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

Automapper v7.0.1

The real scenario (I tried to simplify/make generic for SO): [Source](https://github.com/collinbarrett/FilterLists/blob/master/src/FilterLists.Services/FilterList/MappingProfiles/ListSummaryDtoMappingProfile.cs)  In this real example, the `Languages` and `Tags` members via many-to-many are currently generating N+1 queries.

Comment: Can you provide the sample entity and dto models. Also the AutoMapper version.

Comment: Because AutoMapper [automatically includes ToList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218340/automapper-projectto-adds-tolist-into-child-properties) for you.

Comment: Hi @IvanStoev, I updated the question with the models and the AutoMapper version. Per your second comment, do you know why my mapping profile might be creating N+1 queries if the `ToList()` buffering on subqueries is automatically added by AutoMapper?

Comment: Let me see first if I can reproduce.

Comment: Thanks. I also just added a link to the actual mapping profile I am trying to optimize at the very bottom.

Comment: @IvanStoev see new Update at the top. My apologies, this question is invalid now that I understand AutoMapper adds `ToList()` under the hood. Should I delete this question or vote to close?

Comment: No problem, it happens :) It's up to you, I personally would delete it.

Comment: Hmm, it does seem that the `.ToList()` optimization via Automapper doesn't eliminate `N+1` queries for map configs like: `o.MapFrom(x => x.MyLinkedEntity.MyManyToMany.Select(mm => mm.DistantEntityId)` . But, if I move that save logic into a raw query against `DbContext` (outside of Automapper) and add `.ToList()` to the assignment chain, it reduces `N+1` queries down to just like 2.

Comment: It turns out that when you map to `IEnumerable` of primitive type, AM **does not** add automatically ToList() :( `o.MapFrom(x => x.MyLinkedEntity.MyManyToMany.Select(mm => mm.DistantEntityId).ToList()` should work.

Comment: Or change the destination type from `IEnumerable<int>` to any of `IReadOnlyCollection<int>`, `IReadOnlyList<int>`, `ICollection<int>`, `IList<int>`, `List<int>`, `int[]` etc. :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Yep, just verified that. Thanks! Do you know of any AM discussion/documentation around this? The fact that it works one way for primitives and another for custom types was probably done for a reason, but it makes me a little nervous to rely on.

Comment: P.S. While my question took a rabbit trail, I would say your last two comments, @IvanStoev , answered my questions. If you want to put as an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that AutoMapper *sometimes* automatically adds `ToList` / `ToArray` to the projection expression when mapping enumerable types, sometimes doesn't.

The rule seems to be as follows. If the destination enumerable type is directly assignable from the source expression type, AutoMapper uses directly the source expression. In other words, if the following assignment is valid (pseudo code):

```
dst.Member = src.Expression;
```

In this case, it's up to you to include `ToList` or not in your mapping expression (thus opt-in for EF Core correlated query optimization).

In all other cases AutoMapper performs enumerable element mapping if needed and then adds either `ToArray` or `ToList`. There is no way to opt-out.

Shortly, if the destination enumerable element type if Dto (requires mapping), *don't* include `ToList` in source LINQ expression, if it is primitive or entity type, *do* include `ToList` to avoid N + 1 queries. All this applies if the destination collection type is `IEnumerable<T>`. Any other derived collection type like `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, `IReadOnlyList<T>`, `ICollection<T>`, `IList<T>`, `List<T>`, `T[]` etc. will be handled automatically by AutoMapper in case the source expression returns `IEnumerable<TSource>`.