# "Sequence contains no matching element" while expanding child navigation property with OData & AutoMapper

Tags: .net-core, odata, automapper, entity-framework-core-2.1

The exception "Sequence contains no matching element" occurs while I am trying to expand navigation property using the following query: http://localhost:5000/odata/users?$expand=roles. Request without $expand keyword works. The DTO object is received from `AutoMapper` with very simple mapping configuration.

Please look at the relevant sources:

---

Entity Framework Entities:

```cs
public class User {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

public class Role {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole {
  public string UserId { get; set; }
  public string RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

DTO models:

```cs
public class UserModel {
  public string Id { get; set; }
  public string Username { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
  public IEnumerable<RoleModel> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class RoleModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

`AutoMapper` configuration:

```cs
CreateMap<UserRole, RoleModel>()
     .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.MapFrom(m => m.UserId))
     .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(m => m.Role.Name));

CreateMap<User, UserModel>()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.Roles, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.UserRoles))
     .ReverseMap()
     .ForMember(dest => dest.UserRoles, o => o.Ignore());
```

Controller action method:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<UserModel> Get() =>
    _userManager.Users.ProjectTo<UserModel>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

Actually, exception is thrown by `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.CorrelatedCollectionOptimizingVisitor` while it trying to find WhereClause in expression generated by `AutoMapper`. This line:

```cs
var originalCorrelationPredicate = collectionQueryModel.BodyClauses
    .OfType<WhereClause>()
    .Single(c => c.Predicate is NullSafeEqualExpression);
```

If I change the configuration of `AutoMapper` to the following below, exception is not thrown but Roles subquery is executed separately for every User record:

```cs
CreateMap<User, UserModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Roles, opts => 
          opts.MapFrom(src => 
              src.UserRoles.Select(ur => new RoleModel {
                    Id = ur.UserId,
                    Name = ur.Role.Name
                })))
    .ReverseMap()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.UserRoles, o => o.Ignore());
```

I have checked one more idea: if I am changing action method to call ToList() method on ProjectTo() result then only two queries are executed on DB and no errors are occured. That is why I think the reason for the error in using of OData and AutoMapper at the same time.

What am I doing wrong?

---

Added:

I have checked the execution plan as proposed by @Lucian and found that the only difference between expression that was generated by AutoMapper and another one that was written by hand is the sub-query call.

Hand-written variant (works as it should):

```
.......
Roles = .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(
     $x.UserRoles,
     .Lambda 
#Lambda2<System.Func`2[Test.Data.UserRole,Test.Models.RoleModel]>),
.......
```

Generated by AutoMapper:

```
.......
Roles = .Call System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList(.Call 
     System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(
           $x.UserRoles,
           .Lambda 
#Lambda2<System.Func`2[Test.Data.UserRole,Test.Models.RoleModel]>)),
.......
```

Does anyone know how to force `AutoMapper` not to generate a call to the `ToList()`?

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html). Using the execution plan you can write that query without AM. It might be an EF Core issue.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu, Thank you for your idea. I have added investigated results to post.

Comment: That looks like an EF Core issue to me.

Comment: Workaround https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218340/automapper-projectto-adds-tolist-into-child-properties

Comment: Thank you for link